# send mail using gmail api in android

Tags: sendmail, gmail-api

I am using the code example in the link (SendEmailCtrl.java)  : https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/sending

My activity sends email with example, I add the library `javax.mail:javax.mail-api:1.5.3`

I did not find any more examples how to send mail using the gmail api

```
SharedPreferences settings = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        credential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(
                getApplicationContext(), Arrays.asList(SCOPES))
                .setBackOff(new ExponentialBackOff())
                .setSelectedAccountName(settings.getString(PREF_ACCOUNT_NAME, null));

    mService = new com.google.api.services.gmail.Gmail.Builder(
            transport, jsonFactory, credential)
            .setApplicationName("Gmail API Application")
            .build();

    String accName = this.getIntent().getStringExtra("ACCOUNT");
    Log.d("TienDH", "ViewActivity - acc : " + accName);
    if (accName != null) {

        credential.setSelectedAccountName(accName);
        settings = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
        editor.putString(PREF_ACCOUNT_NAME, accName);
        editor.commit();

        try {
            MimeMessage mm = SendMailCtrl.createEmail(accName, "yaraht2011@gmail.com", "Test", "test send mail API");
            SendMailCtrl.sendMessage(mService, accName, mm);
            Log.d("TienDH", "sent mail");
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

When I am running the app I am getting this error:

```
 Process: com.fourlines.gmailapi, PID: 8270
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.sun.mail.util.MailLogger
            at javax.mail.Session.initLogger(Session.java:226)
            at javax.mail.Session.<init>(Session.java:210)
            at javax.mail.Session.getDefaultInstance(Session.java:321)
            at com.fourlines.gmailapi.SendMailCtrl.createEmail(SendMailCtrl.java:80)
            at com.fourlines.gmailapi.ViewEmailActivity.onCreate(ViewEmailActivity.java:68)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5275)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2166)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2252)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1200)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:606)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: i'm struggling with the same problem here. I guess google have to make tutorials for using the gmail api. please if you have any solution tell me.

Comment: Have you imported Java Mail, Additional and Activation Libraries ?